# Ставлю Margin 0 На body но не работает

Tags: html, css

Пишу себе код, и замечаю что между body и границей браузера есть место которое видно на первой картинке, но я помню что поставил body{ margin: 0%;}, см. 2 картинку, потом захожу в Dev Tools(вроде так называется), и мне показывает что всё ещё есть 8 пикселей, но я не понимаю как раз я их обнулил

[image: первая картинка]   [image: картинка 2][image: третья картинка]

Comment: Обнови страницу при помощи Crtl+F5

Comment: я работаю на лайв сервере, обновление не требуется

Comment: А вы уверены, что стили подключены? Ну малоли.. И все же может `margin: 0;`? Как-то более привычнее.

Comment: У вас два оператора с боди. Видимо один оператор с 0 находится до оператора с 8

Comment: Вы приложили только фрагмент css кода. Приложите, пожалуйста, весь код - тогда можно будет делать какие-либо выводы.

Answer (score 0):

- 1. Вариант
     Позаботитесь о том что бы ваше обнуление было ниже того коде где отступ 8 пикселей или добавьте !important после css свойства. !important -- делает css свойство как бы сильнее остальных.

Рекомендую изучить как работает наследование в CSS https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance

```
body {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

- 2. Вариант
     Если вы используете сторонние библиотеки (bootstrap например) подключайте их выше вашего CSS кода.
- 3. **Вариант почистите кэш. CSS мог просто кэшироваться.**
     Также можно открыть кэш на время разработки. Откройте инструменты разработчика и во вкладке "сеть" нажать галочку "отключить кэш". Кэш будет отключён пока открыта консоль разработчика.

Comment: Решил данную проблему самостоятельно, убрав последнюю линию кода, но всё равно спасибо за советы